# Where should I discuss tags that are only relevant to some users?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Where should I discuss a tag that's only relevant to some users?

In my case, I've noticed that the [hash](/questions/tagged/hash) tag is being used by [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) folk (and users of related tags) when I suspect [hash-map](/questions/tagged/hash-map) ought to be used instead.

I tried mentioning it in the Ruby/Rails chatroom, but no-one's replied there.

Is mentioning it in meta appropriate?

Comment: Isn't basically every single tag only relevant to a part of SO's userbase?

Comment: @sth: Some are equally relevant to everyone, such as "homework", and sometimes you're just talking about general principles, such as "should tags include dashes?" or "should tags exist for different versions?".

Answer (score 3):

If a question is incorrectly tagged, consider retagging it.

If a tag is constantly misused, **write/rewrite its tag wiki** to explain the correct usage and evaluate whether the tag is actually useful in the first place.

Both [hash](/questions/tagged/hash) and [hash-map](/questions/tagged/hash-map) seen fine to me, so it's probably just "habit" — users see one question wrongly tagged [hash](/questions/tagged/hash) and then tag theirs the same way.  Eliminating the misuse and explaining the proper use in the tag wiki should help to prevent future misuse.

Leaving a comment when you retag might be a good idea, but contacting people specifically shouldn't be needed.